# Leafletjs dragg market only one axis

Tags: javascript, leaflet

How to protect dragged marker position latitude and to enable drag marker only longitude axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `dragstart` and `drag` events to handle this. You save the marker position when you start dragging and then you reset the latitude all the time when the `drag` event is emitted.

```
//Marker position before dragging
var latLngBeforeDrag;

//On drag start
function onDragStart(e){
    var marker = e.target;
    latLngBeforeDrag = marker.getLatLng();
}

//On drag
function onDrag(e){
    var marker = e.target;
    marker.setLatLng(L.latLng(latLngBeforeDrag.lat, marker.getLatLng().lng));
}

//Create new marker
var marker = L.marker([36.83711,-2.464459], {draggable:true});
marker.on('dragstart', onDragStart);
marker.on('drag', onDrag);
//Add marker to map
marker.addTo(map);
```

Se example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guspersson/dztmt287/)